# How to integrate annotation in opentok?

Tags: annotations, opentok, tokbox

I am using opentok for video feeding in my application.

How to integrate annotations on opentok using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As Darshu mentioned, you can use the [OpenTok Annotation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opentok-annotation) node module to add annotations to your OpenTok application in JavaScript. You can also find sample applications in JavaScript using OpenTok and OpenTok Annotation package here: https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-sample-apps-js

Answer (score 0):

[OpenTok Accelerator Sample Apps for JavaScript](https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-sample-apps-js) 
open here soultion available. First download nodejs install on the machine.

This document shows you how to prepare and run the sample application. The app is built using Accelerator Core JS and the following accelerator packs:
Text Chat
Screen Sharing
Annotation